# Python items in a list still a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to create a short script where 5 random numbers from an available list are selected and then each one is displayed. The problem I'm having is that the list to which I'm appending the results returns a list as well, not integers or strings. Here's the code:

```
def randomStar(self):
    choice = [5,4,3]
    probability = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]
    star = random.choices(choice, probability)
    return star

multi = []
characters = []
for x in range(5):
    star = randomStar(x)
    multi.append(star)
    x += 1

for star in multi:
    characters.append(star)
print (characters)
print (multi)
```

Both multi and characters lists return:

```
['[3]', '[3]', '[3]', '[5]', '[3]']
```

So when I try  to iterate through "Multi" list I still get lists. How can I get the values only? Or is the way I'm appending the numbers to the list incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: Those aren't lists. They're strings, that represent lists (the ones you show are valid list literals, anyway). It's not clear *how*, given that you don't actually appear to convert to strings anywhere. Please give an actual [mcve].

Comment: ok, when I display each item I get something like [3], [4] etc. How can I get only the number like 3,4?

Comment: That's all the code I have, the only thing more is that I'm importing random module. There's nothing else to add

Comment: No, that's not true. `randomStar` returns a list of a single integer. You append that to a list. That is *not* the output you then show, which is a list of *strings representing lists of a single integer*. Your question is internally inconsistent. But, as you were told yesterday, if you want the item from that list you can just use an index like with any other list.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `self` argument to the function? Also, `x += 1` in the loop does not make any sense. It seems like you have a misunderstanding of some basic Python concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are lists because `random.choices` returns "a k sized list of elements".

Since there is only one element in the list, and this is what you are trying to return, you just want to write `return star[0]`.

Comment: This was it! Thanks!